# Timer in javaScript doesnt work

Tags: javascript, html, timer, countdowntimer

I am making a simple timer in javaScript which starts when you click anywhere in the document and it resets on clicking again.

```
var k = 0,
  m = 0,
  s = 0;
document.onclick =
  function() {
    k = 0;
    setTimeout(function() {
      k++;

      if (Math.floor(k / 6000) > 1) {
        m = Math.floor(k / 6000);
        s = Math.floor(k % 6000);
      } else
        s = Math.floor(k / 100);
      document.getElementById('input3').value = "0" + m + ":" + "0" + s + "  " + k;
    }, 10);
  };
```

input3 is the id of textbox in html in timer in which countdown is displayed

Comment: Please define "_doesnt work_".

Comment: `setTimeout()` schedules a function to be invoked **once**.  You may be interested in the related function `setInterval()`.

Comment: Thank you everyone

Answer (score 2):

What you probably want is `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`.

I made this example that sounds like what you want. https://jsfiddle.net/5yke1hmp/

Comment: @sanjaybisht Thanks!  If you like it, do you mind selecting it as the correct answer and maybe giving it an upvote?

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout(function() {` is the problem, if you want to create a timer you should use `setInterval(function() {`

setInterval will execute the function after every ''specified time' while setTimeout will only run the function once after 'specified time'